# connecting eclipse to PHP,MYSQL log in and register

Tags: php, android, mysql, eclipse

i wonder why i cant connect my application to my PHP,SQL Wamp server. here is my code, is this a problem of compatibility in my WAMP server? when the application starts to connect to server it force close. can any one help thanks!

also one question how can i make this application online that can log in on the app. in cellphone and connect to my wampserver on my PC. which IP should i use? i've tried using http://192.168.MY-IPADDRESS/learn2crack_login_api but it doesnt work. thank you in advance for your answers !

```
private JSONParser jsonParser;

//URL of the PHP API
private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/learn2crack_login_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/learn2crack_login_api/";
private static String forpassURL = "http://10.0.2.2/learn2crack_login_api/";
private static String chgpassURL = "http://10.0.2.2/learn2crack_login_api/";


private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";
private static String forpass_tag = "forpass";
private static String chgpass_tag = "chgpass";


// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * Function to Login
 **/

public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function to change password
 **/

public JSONObject chgPass(String newpas, String email){
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", chgpass_tag));

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newpas", newpas));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(chgpassURL, params);
    return json;
}





/**
 * Function to reset the password
 **/

public JSONObject forPass(String forgotpassword){
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", forpass_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("forgotpassword", forgotpassword));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(forpassURL, params);
    return json;
}






 /**
  * Function to  Register
  **/
public JSONObject registerUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL,params);
    return json;
}


/**
 * Function to logout user
 * Resets the temporary data stored in SQLite Database
 * */
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    db.resetTables();
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you writing "connecting eclipse..." ?

Comment: 10.2.2 is not a valid IP address